# Port forward on router logic

Tags: router, portforwarding

After port forwarded in the router, does it mean that the port is opened even I didn't use it? From my current situation, the port is closed while I am not using it. But what can trigger the port to be open?

Shutdown my port forwarded PC will turn off the port too?

My actual problem now:
I port forwarded a port, and the port is closed when I did not open any application that uses the port. I want to know why.

Comment: Is the port open where? On the PC? How can the router force the PC to open a port?

Comment: Yes, on the pc, but the setting is on the router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a piece of networking infrastructure (your router) cannot force a PC to open a port. Think about what opening a port actually means: There is some program (or OS) that opens the port and listens to it. How can the router force the PC to do this?

Comment: If that make sense, then why we set the port forward on the router and not the PC? If port forward is set on PC, meaning that we have to do some setting on it, but we didn't.